# Plot datetime.date / time series in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, datetime

I created a pandas dataframe from some value counts on particular calendar dates. Here is how I did it:

```py
time_series = pd.DataFrame(df['Operation Date'].value_counts().reset_index())
time_series.columns = ['date', 'count']
```

Basically, it is two columns, the first "date" is a column with `datetime.date` objects and the second column, "count" are simply integer values. Now, I'd like to plot a scatter or a KDE to represent how the value changes over the calendar days.

But when I try:

```py
time_series.plot(kind='kde')
plt.show()
```

I get a plot where the x-axis is from -50 to 150 as if it is parsing the `datetime.date` objects as integers somehow. Also, it is yielding two identical plots rather than just one.

Any idea how I can plot them and see the calendars day along the x-axis?

Comment: a scatter is not a KDE and it is not even clear what you are asking for. write down some reproducible data.

Comment: Here is what my dataframe looks like: 
    `2016-08-05    65`, 
    `2016-11-23    34`     etc. How can I plot these?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

you sure you got datetime? i just tried this and it worked fine:

```
df =    date    count
7   2012-06-11 16:51:32 1.0
3   2012-09-28 08:05:14 12.0
19  2012-10-01 18:01:47 4.0
2   2012-10-03 15:18:23 29.0
6   2012-12-22 19:50:43 4.0
1   2013-02-19 19:54:03 28.0
9   2013-02-28 16:08:40 17.0
12  2013-03-12 08:42:55 6.0
4   2013-04-04 05:27:27 6.0
17  2013-04-18 09:40:37 29.0
11  2013-05-17 16:34:51 22.0
5   2013-07-07 14:32:59 16.0
14  2013-10-22 06:56:29 13.0
13  2014-01-16 23:08:46 20.0
15  2014-02-25 00:49:26 10.0
18  2014-03-19 15:58:38 25.0
0   2014-03-31 05:53:28 16.0
16  2014-04-01 09:59:32 27.0
8   2014-04-27 12:07:41 17.0
10  2014-09-20 04:42:39 21.0

df = df.sort_values('date', ascending=True)
plt.plot(df['date'], df['count'])
plt.xticks(rotation='vertical')
```

[image]

EDIT:

if you want a scatter plot you can:

```
plt.plot(df['date'], df['count'], '*')
plt.xticks(rotation='vertical')
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if it's too late, but I'd want to know 'plt' stays for what?

Comment: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Answer (score 1):

If the column is datetime dtype (not object), then you can **call `plot()` directly on the dataframe**. You don't need to sort by date either, it's done behind the scenes if x-axis is datetime.

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df.plot(x='date', y='count', kind='scatter', rot='vertical');
```

[image: res]

You can also pass many arguments to make the plot nicer (add titles, change figsize and fontsize, rotate ticklabels, set subplots axis etc.) See the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) for full list of possible arguments.

```py
df.plot(x='date', y='count', kind='line', rot=45, legend=None, 
        title='Count across time', xlabel='', fontsize=10, figsize=(12,4));
```

[image: res2]

You can even use another column to color scatter plots. In the example below, the months are used to assign color. Tip: To get the full list of possible colormaps, pass any gibberish string to `colormap` and the error message will show you the full list.

```py
df.plot(x='date', y='count', kind='scatter', rot=90, c=df['date'].dt.month, colormap='tab20', sharex=False);
```

[image: res4]