# Plot - x must be a label or position

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, data-science, line-plot

I have a DataFrame df as below

```
      Date     Confirmed    Deaths  Recovered
0   2020-01-30    1           0         0
1   2020-01-31    0           0         0
2   2020-02-01    0           0         0
3   2020-02-02    1           0         0
4   2020-02-03    1           0         0
```

While Trying to plot Date VS Confirmed

```
df.plot(kind ='line',x='Date',y='Confirmed')
```

I get the following error

> ValueError: x must be a label or position

The Datatype of the columns are

```
Date         object
Confirmed     int64
Deaths        int64
Recovered     int64
dtype: object
```

Comment: Maybe because your Date is of type object.
try it this way https://stackoverflow.com/a/41815888/2287841

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code snippet is perfectly fine.
I suspect an issue in your instance type of Date column in the dataframe itself.

Try this:

```
from pandas.core.dtypes.generic import ABCSeries
print(isinstance(df["Date"], ABCSeries))
```

If this returns `False`, you can be sure that Date column is not created with a proper instance type in the dataframe.
You can try converting your date column to datetime objects using `pd.to_datetime()`

Answer (score 1):

```
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

Try changing the datatype of the Date column from Object to datetime64[ns] datatype.

PS: Don't forget to import pandas as pd. ↓

```
import pandas as pd
```